# Position went wrong

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Ok not everything but something went wrong for the color coding and nothing seems to help please guide me it's at [this site](http://www.ethanmckenzie.altervista.org/creator.html) and the code is all here:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<!--<script type="text/javascript">(function(a,b,c){if(c in b&&b[c]){var d,e=a.location,f=/^(a|html)$/i;a.addEventListener("click",function(a){d=a.target;while(!f.test(d.nodeName))d=d.parentNode;"href"in d&&(d.href.indexOf("http")||~d.href.indexOf(e.host))&&(a.preventDefault(),e.href=d.href)},!1)}})(document,window.navigator,"standalone")</script>-->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type = "text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".fontcolors").hide();
$(".ncolors").hide();
$(".pcolors").hide();
$("#imggg").hide();
$(".colors").hide();
$(".plushead").click(function(){
$("#heading").css({ "font-size": "+=2px"});
});
$(".minushead").click(function(){
$("#heading").css({ "font-size": "-=2px"});
});
$(".plusname").click(function(){
$("#name").css({ "font-size": "+=2px"});
});
$(".minusname").click(function(){
$("#name").css({ "font-size": "-=2px"});
});
$(".plusbody").click(function(){
$("#body").css({ "font-size": "+=2px"});
});
$(".minusbody").click(function(){
$("#body").css({ "font-size": "-=2px"});
});
$(".hider").click(function(){
$("#custom").hide();
});
$("#next1").click(function(){
$(".colors").slideToggle();
$("#heads").slideToggle();
});
$("#next2").click(function(){
$(".colors").slideToggle();
$(".fontcolors").slideToggle();
});
});
</script>
<!--<script type="text/javascript">
var a=document.getElementsByTagName("a");
for(var i=0;i<a.length;i++)
{
    a[i].onclick=function()
    {
        window.location=this.getAttribute("href");
        return false
    }
}
self.scrollView.scrollEnabled = false;

- (void)killScroll 
{
    CGPoint offset = scrollView.contentOffset;
    [scrollView setContentOffset:offset animated:NO];
}
- (void)killScroll 
{
    CGPoint offset = scrollView.contentOffset;
    offset.x -= 1.0;
    offset.y -= 1.0;
    [scrollView setContentOffset:offset animated:NO];
    offset.x += 1.0;
    offset.y += 1.0;
    [scrollView setContentOffset:offset animated:NO];
    
}
document.ontouchstart = function(e){ 
    e.preventDefault(); 
}
</script>-->
<script type="text/javascript">
function readURL(input) {
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = function (e) {
            document.getElementById('blah').src =  e.target.result;
        }

        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
}
</script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="generator" content="AlterVista - Editor HTML"/>
  <title>Create</title>
 <style type="text/css">
 .remote {
 font-family: vevey;
 color: black;
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 50px;
 }
 #imgInp::-webkit-file-upload-button {
  visibility: hidden;
}
 #custom {
padding: 5px;
width: 400px;
/*border-bottom-left-radius: 15px;
border-bottom-right-radius: 15px;*/
/*padding-top: 20px;
padding-bottom: 20px; */
visibility: visible;
margin-top: -527px;
background-color: white;
/*-webkit-filter: blur(20px);*/
border: 1px solid   black;
border-radius: 2px;
}
body {
transition: all .5s ease;
-webkit-transition: all .5s ease;
}
a {
text-decoration: none;
color:   white;
}
.colors {
margin-left: 60px;
margin-top: 0px;
}
.fontcolors {
margin-left: 60px;
}
.ncolors {
margin-left: 60px;
}
.pcolors {
margin-left: 60px;
}

#namo {
width: 38px;
}
.red {
height: 50px;
width: 50px;
background-color: #ff6a6a;
 border-radius: 100%; 
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.blue {
height: 50px;
width: 50px;
background-color: #8ad3ff;
 border-radius: 100%; 
  border: 1px solid black;
margin-top: -51px;
margin-left: 208px;
}
.green {
height: 50px;
width: 50px;
background-color: #8aff9e;
 border-radius: 100%; 
  border: 1px solid black;
margin-top: -51px;
margin-left: 156px;
}
.orange {
height: 50px;
width: 50px;
background-color: #ffbd6a;
 border-radius: 100%; 
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-top: -51px;
margin-left: 52px;

}

.yellow {
height: 50px;
width: 50px;
background-color: #fffb93;
 border-radius: 100%; 
  border: 1px solid black;
margin-top: -51px;
margin-left: 104px;
}
.purple {
background-color: #d58aff;
 border-radius: 100%; 
height: 50px;
width: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
margin-left: 25px;
margin-top: -10px;
}

.black {
height: 50px;
width: 50px;
background-color: #181818;
 border-radius: 100%; 
  border: 1px solid black;
margin-top: -51px;
margin-left: 181px;
}
.white {
height: 50px;
width: 50px;
background-color: #EBEBEB;
 border-radius: 100%; 
  border: 1px solid black;
margin-top: -51px;
margin-left: 129px;
}
.pink {
height: 50px;
width: 50px;
background-color: #ffa4e9;
 border-radius: 100%; 
  border: 1px solid black;
margin-top: -51px;
margin-left: 77px;
}
<!--#square {
height: 50px;
width: 50px;
background-color: black;
 border-radius: 100%; 
border: 1px solid   white;
}
#circle {
height: 50px;
width: 50px;
background-color: black;
 border-radius: 100%;
border: 1px solid   white;

}-->
.paragr {
 border-radius: 100%; 
height: 50px;
width: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
font-family: paragraph;
font-size: 50px;
line-height: 50px;
text-align: center;
background-color:   white;
color: black;
}
.lol {
 border-radius: 100%; 
height: 50px;
width: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
font-family: lol;
font-size: 40px;
line-height: 50px;
text-align: center;
background-color:   white;
color: black;
}
.fon {
 border-radius: 100%; 
height: 50px;
width: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
font-family: font;
font-size: 40px;
line-height: 50px;
text-align: center;
background-color:   white;
color: black;
}
.boringthin {
height: 50px;
width: 50px;
 border-radius: 100%; 
  border: 1px solid black;
font-family: boringthin;
font-size: 40px;
line-height: 50px;
text-align: center;
background-color:   white;
color: black;
}
.chunky {
 border-radius: 100%; 
height: 50px;
width: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
font-family: chunky;
font-size: 40px;
line-height: 50px;
text-align: center;
background-color:   white;
color: black;
margin-left: 25px;
margin-top: -10px;
}
.fancy {
 border-radius: 100%; 
height: 50px;
width: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
font-family: fancy;
font-size: 40px;
line-height: 50px;
text-align: center;
background-color:   white;
color: black;
}
.handx {
 border-radius: 100%; 
height: 50px;
width: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
font-family: handx;
font-size: 40px;
line-height: 50px;
text-align: center;
background-color:   white;
color: black;
}
#cash {
 border-radius: 100%; 
height: 50px;
width: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
font-family: handx;
font-size: 40px;
line-height: 50px;
text-align: center;
background-color:   white;
color: black;
}
.vevey {
 border-radius: 100%; 
height: 50px;
width: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
font-family: vevey;
font-size: 40px;
line-height: 50px;
text-align: center;
background-color:   white;
color: black;
}
.plus {
 border-radius: 100%; 
height: 50px;
width: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
font-family: vevey;
font-size: 80px;
line-height: 50px;
text-align: center;
background-color:   white;
color: black;
}
.minus {
 border-radius: 100%; 
height: 50px;
width: 50px;
border: 1px solid black;
font-family: vevey;
font-size: 80px;
line-height: 50px;
text-align: center;
background-color: white;
color: black;
}
@font-face {
    font-family: font;
    src: url(tallfilm.ttf);
}
@font-face {
    font-family: lol;
    src: url(lol.otf);
}
@font-face {
    font-family: boringthin;
    src: url(boringthin.otf);
}
@font-face {
    font-family: chunky;
    src: url(chunky.otf);
}
@font-face {
    font-family: fancy;
    src: url(fancy.ttf);
}
@font-face {
    font-family: handx;
    src: url(hand.otf);
}
@font-face {
    font-family: paragraph;
    src: url(paragraph.otf);
}
@font-face {
    font-family: vevey;
    src: url(vevey.ttf);
}
@font-face {
    font-family: remote;
    src: url(remote.ttf);
}
#heading {
font-family: font, sans-serif;
text-align: center;
font-size: 100px;
transition: all .5s ease;
-webkit-transition: all .5s ease;
}
#body {
text-align: center;
font-family: lol, sans-serif;
font-size: 23px;
margin-top: -0px;
transition: color .5s ease;
-webkit-transition: color .5s ease;
width: 1000px;
}
#name {
text-align: center;
font-family: lol, sans-serif;
font-size: 17px;
margin-top: -120px;
transition: all .5s ease;
-webkit-transition: all .5s ease;

}
.heading {
font-family: font, sans-serif;
background-color: white;
font-size: 25px;
border: 1px solid   black;
}
.paragraph {
font-family: font, sans-serif;
background-color: white;
font-size: 25px;
border: 1px solid   black;
}
.name {
font-family: font, sans-serif;
background-color: white;
font-size: 25px;
border: 1px solid   black;
}

#heads {
margin-left: 62px;
}
/*#userinput {
width: 150px;
}
#userinput2 {
width: 150px;
}
#userinput3 {
width: 150px;
}
input:nth-child(1) {
width: 112px;
}
input:nth-child(3) {
width: 112px;
}
input:nth-child(5) {
width: 112px;
} */
.hide {
margin-left: 80px;
font-family: font, sans-serif;
background-color: white;
font-size: 25px;
color: black;
}
.hider {
color: black;
text-decoration: none;
}
.next {
font-family: font, sans-serif;
background-color: white;
font-size: 25px;
border: 1px solid   black;
width: 50px;
text-align: center;
}
#imgtxt {
font-size: 40px;
font-family: vevey;
margin-top: -50px;
margin-left: 20px;
}
#blah {
height: 250px;
width: 250px;
font-size: 20px;
font-family: boringthin;
border: 2px solid;
border-radius: 5px;
}
#imgInp {
background-color: white;
font-family: boringthin;
width: 50px;
height: 50px;
border: 1px solid black;
border-radius: 100%;
}
div {
transition: all 1s ease;
}
</style>
   <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
   
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="iconic.png" />
<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" href="/backgroundx.jpg">
<link rel="icon" 
      type="image/png" 
      href="iconic.png">
</head>
<body>
<center>
<p id='heading'>Head</p>
<p id='name'>Name</p>
<img id="blah" src="#" alt="Square Image" />
<br />
<p id='body'>Body</p>
</center>
<script type ="text/javascript">
function background(color) {
  document.bgColor = color;
  }
function fontp(fontx) {
  document.getElementById("body").style.fontFamily = fontx;
  }
  function fonth(fontn) {
  document.getElementById("heading").style.fontFamily = fontn;
  }
  function fontn(fontc) {
  document.getElementById("name").style.fontFamily = fontc;
  }
  function paragraph(pcolor) {
  document.getElementById("body").style.color = pcolor;
  document.getElementById("blah").style.borderColor = pcolor;
  }
   function square(amt) {
  document.getElementsByTagName("div").style.borderRadius = amt;
  }
   function circle(amt) {
  document.getElementsByTagName("div").style.borderRadius = amt;
  }
  function namec(ncolor) {
  document.getElementById("name").style.color = ncolor;
  }
function fontcolor(fontcolor1) {
  document.getElementById("heading").style.color = fontcolor1;
  }
 function appear() {
  document.getElementById("custom").style.visibility = "visible";
  }
  function hide() {
  document.getElementById("custom").style.visibility = "hidden";
  }
function changeText2(){
 var userInput = document.getElementById('userInput').value;
 document.getElementById('heading').innerHTML = userInput;
}
function changeText3(){
 var userInput = document.getElementById('userInput2').value;
 document.getElementById('body').innerHTML = userInput;
}
function changeText4(){
 var userInput = document.getElementById('userInput3').value;
 document.getElementById('name').innerHTML = userInput;
}

</script>

<div id="custom">
<div class="colors">
<div class="remote">Background Colors</div>
<a href="#" onClick="javascript:background('#ff6a6a')"><div class="red"></div></a>
<a href="#" onClick="javascript:background('#ffbd6a')"><div class="orange"></div></a>
<a href="#" onClick="javascript:background('#fffb93')"><div class="yellow"></div></a>
<a href="#" onClick="javascript:background('#8aff9e')"><div class="green"></div></a>
<a href="#" onClick="javascript:background('#8ad3ff')"><div class="blue"></div></a>
<a href="#" onClick="javascript:background('#d58aff')"><div class="purple"></div></a>
<a href="#" onClick="javascript:background('#ffa4e9')"><div class="pink"></div></a>
<a href="#" onClick="javascript:background('#EBEBEB')"><div class="white"></div></a>
<a href="#" onClick="javascript:background('#333333')"><div class="black"></div></a>
<div id="next2" class="next">Next</div>
</div>
<div id="imggg">
<input type='file' id="imgInp" onchange="readURL(this);" /><p id="imgtxt">X</p>
</div>
<div class="fontcolors">
<div class="remote">Heading Colors</div>
<a href="#" onClick="javascript:fontcolor('#ff6a6a')"><div class="red"></div></a>
<a href="#" onClick="javascript:fontcolor('#ffbd6a')"><div class="orange"></div></a>
<a href="#" onClick="javascript:fontcolor('#fffb93')"><div class="yellow"></div></a>
<a href="#" onClick="javascript:fontcolor('#8aff9e')"><div class="green"></div></a>
<a href="#" onClick="javascript:fontcolor('#8ad3ff')"><div class="blue"></div></a>
<a href="#" onClick="javascript:fontcolor('#d58aff')"><div class="purple"></div></a>
<a href="#" onClick="javascript:fontcolor('#ffa4e9')"><div class="pink"></div></a>
<a href="#" onClick="javascript:fontcolor('#EBEBEB')"><div class="white"></div></a>
<a href="#" onClick="javascript:fontcolor('#333333')"><div class="black"></div></a>
<a href="#" onClick="javascript:fonth('chunky')"><div class="chunky">E</div></a>
<a href="#" onClick="javascript:fonth('lol')"><div class="lol">E</div></a>
<a href="#" onClick="javascript:fonth('boringthin')"><div class="boringthin">E</div></a>
<a href="#" onClick="javascript:fonth('handx')"><div class="handx">E</div></a>
<a href="#" onClick="javascript:fonth('font')"><div class="fon">E</div></a>
<a href="#" onClick="javascript:fonth('vevey')"><div class="vevey">E</div></a>
<a href="#" class="plushead"><div class="plus">+</div></a>
<a href="#" class="minushead"><div class="minus">-</div></a>
</div>

<div class="ncolors">
<div class="remote">Name Color</div>
<a href="#" onClick="javascript:namec('#ff6a6a')"><div class="red"></div></a>
<a href="#" onClick="javascript:namec('#ffbd6a')"><div class="orange"></div></a>
<a href="#" onClick="javascript:namec('#fffb93')"><div class="yellow"></div></a>
<a href="#" onClick="javascript:namec('#8aff9e')"><div class="green"></div></a>
<a href="#" onClick="javascript:namec('#8ad3ff')"><div class="blue"></div></a>
<a href="#" onClick="javascript:namec('#d58aff')"><div class="purple"></div></a>
<a href="#" onClick="javascript:namec('#ffa4e9')"><div class="pink"></div></a>
<a href="#" onClick="javascript:namec('#EBEBEB')"><div class="white"></div></a>
<a href="#" onClick="javascript:namec('#333333')"><div class="black"></div></a>
<a href="#" onClick="javascript:fontn('chunky')"><div class="chunky">E</div></a>
<a href="#" onClick="javascript:fontn('lol')"><div class="lol">E</div></a>
<a href="#" onClick="javascript:fontn('boringthin')"><div class="boringthin">E</div></a>
<a href="#" onClick="javascript:fontn('handx')"><div class="handx">E</div></a>
<a href="#" onClick="javascript:fontn('fancy')"><div class="fancy">E</div></a>
<a href="#" onClick="javascript:fontn('vevey')"><div class="vevey">E</div></a>
<a href="#" class="plusname"><div class="plus">+</div></a>
<a href="#" class="minusname"><div class="minus">-</div></a>
</div>

<div class="pcolors">
<div class="remote">Body</div>
<a href="#" onClick="javascript:paragraph('#ff6a6a')"><div class="red"></div></a>
<a href="#" onClick="javascript:paragraph('#ffbd6a')"><div class="orange"></div></a>
<a href="#" onClick="javascript:paragraph('#fffb93')"><div class="yellow"></div></a>
<a href="#" onClick="javascript:paragraph('#8aff9e')"><div class="green"></div></a>
<a href="#" onClick="javascript:paragraph('#8ad3ff')"><div class="blue"></div></a>
<a href="#" onClick="javascript:paragraph('#9450ff')"><div class="purple"></div></a>
<a href="#" onClick="javascript:paragraph('#ffa4e9')"><div class="pink"></div></a>
<a href="#" onClick="javascript:paragraph('#EBEBEB')"><div class="white"></div></a>
<a href="#" onClick="javascript:paragraph('#333333')"><div class="black"></div></a>
<a href="#" onClick="javascript:fontp('paragraph')"><div class="paragr">E</div></a>
<a href="#" onClick="javascript:fontp('lol')"><div class="lol">E</div></a>
<a href="#" onClick="javascript:fontp('boringthin')"><div class="boringthin">E</div></a>
<a href="#" onClick="javascript:fontp('handx')"><div class="handx">E</div></a>
<a href="#" onClick="javascript:fontp('fancy')"><div class="fancy">E</div></a>
<a href="#" onClick="javascript:fontp('vevey')"><div class="vevey">E</div></a>
<a href="#" class="plusbody"><div class="plus">+</div></a>
<a href="#" class="minusbody"><div class="minus">-</div></a>
<div class="hide"><a class="hider">Hide</a></div>
</div>
<div id="heads">
<div class="remote">Your Text</div>
<input type='text' id='userInput' value='' class="heading" />
<input type='button' onclick='changeText2()' value='Head' class="heading"/>
<br />
 <input type='text' id='userInput3' value='' class="name" />
<input type='button' onclick='changeText4()' value='Name' class="name" id="namo"/>
<br />
<input type='text' id='userInput2' value='' class="paragraph" />
<input type='button' onclick='changeText3()' value='Body' class="paragraph"/>
<div id="next1" class="next">Next</div>
</div>
</div>
<!--<script>
    document.body.addEventListener('touchmove', function(event) {
      console.log(event.source);
      //if (event.source == document.body)
        event.preventDefault();
    }, false);
 
    window.onresize = function() {
      $(document.body).width(window.innerWidth).height(window.innerHeight);
    }
 
    $(function() {
      window.onresize();
    });
  </script>-->
</body>
</html>
```

It's sloppy and all wrong but I'm so tired and dead inside I need someone I'll pay you as much as I can in whatever currency you people use here

Comment: what you want exactly to do, explain more please.

Comment: You need to pare down your wall of code to a [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: "I'll pay you as much as I can", that's not how it works at StackOverflow, we'll do it for free (and votes) if you help us help you by narrowing down the problem and code. Break your code into smaller pieces, by doing this there is a good chance you will discover the answer yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right-click and Inspect Element on the circles and you'll see the problem. The a-tags with the onclick attributes are tiny; they aren't the size of the circle divs and you're not actually clicking on them when you click the circles. Get rid of the a-tags around the divs and move the onclick attributes to the divs themselves. Like this:

```
<div class="red" onClick="javascript:background('#ff6a6a')"></div>
<div class="orange" onClick="javascript:background('#ffbd6a')"></div>
<div class="yellow" onClick="javascript:background('#fffb93')"></div>
<div class="green" onClick="javascript:background('#8aff9e')"></div>
<div class="blue" onClick="javascript:background('#8ad3ff')"></div>
<div class="purple" onClick="javascript:background('#d58aff')"></div>
<div class="pink" onClick="javascript:background('#ffa4e9')"></div>
<div class="white" onClick="javascript:background('#EBEBEB')"></div>
<div class="black" onClick="javascript:background('#333333')"></div>
```

To avoid hardcoding the color values like that, you could just change every single one of those onclicks to "background(this.className)", since all your classnames are built-in html colors.

Comment: thank you so much I love you god bless you. good people really do exist :') is there anything I can do for you? please?

Comment: Actually, I'd mostly like to help you with this project more. I'm not sure what you're trying to do but it seems like you could use some guidance on a broader scale than StackOverflow posts. Add a link on your profile to some website/account where I can message you (e.g. email, Linkedin, Youtube, anything) and we can talk about what you're doing, if you'd like.

Comment: ethan.mckenzie@aol.com That would be so great because I'm such a sloppy newish coder and I need guidance more than anything thank you so much!